# Dual monitors on nVidia GeForce 9600 GT

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, vga, dvi

I have an nVidia GeForce 9600GT*, which has (only) two DVI connectors. I have one connected to a 22" LCD panel and the other empty. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 successfully.

I have a second LCD panel, but it only has a VGA port. The motherboard has a VGA connector, but the nVidia does not.

Can/should I connect the second monitor to the VGA port? Will this result in a standard "dual monitor" configuration?

*Mine doesn't look nearly as fancy as [this](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9600-gt) though. Mine is a normal PCI card with a large, red, finned heat-sink on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are good that inside of windows, such a configuration would work.  However, in linux I cannot say.  The best option either way is to use the 9600gt, and purchase a dvi>vga converter.

http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041903&p_id=2396&seq=1&format=2

Not very pricey, and worth it for the end result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks -- it worked. Now I have to set the correct monitor resolution somehow (http://askubuntu.com/questions/262432/native-resolution-not-available-in-displays-unity)